# Disable HTTPS Certificate Validation in FIPS mode

Tags: java, security, ssl, fips

There is a code in java which performs HTTPS call and then ignores the incoming certificate validation. In order to do this the custom trust manager is implemented.
But now we need to switch to FIPS mode. And in fips mode the following exception is received when the custom trustmanager is used by SSL Socket.

**FIPS mode: only SunJSSE TrustManagers may be used**

So is there a way to bypass the incoming certificate verification in a FIPS mode?

Comment: Bypassing certificate verification is as secure as shouting your secrets from your local rooftop. It’s an awful thing to do and should never have been done. Fix it.

Comment: Thanks and Agree! But I need to handle an existing code. So I need a way to do that.

Comment: With whilst being FIPS compliant! Someone disabled SSL - you’re sending traffic in plaintext. That’s simply not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for comment!

Comment: Actually I am not saying sending the plaintext, but ssl, just disabling the incoming certificate verification. If this is allowed by FIPS ?

Comment: Disabling incoming certificate verification disables the verification of the sending party. SSL with certificate verification turned off is identical to plain text. You obviously do not understand enough about ssl for the task you have been asked to do. I’m afraid my only recommendation would be to hire a professional.

Comment: OK. I understand your point. I just need to report to my manager that the task we have requires major redesign. This is why I am trying to figure out if there is any possible solution. Anyway thank you very much and sorry for asking this probably stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically asking if you can enable a specific security level (FIPS) while disabling some of the security required in this level. No - the whole point of this security level is to ensure that specific security requirements are met, and proper certificate validation is an essential requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Is there any reference of FIPS document where I can get this?

Comment: @user2420079: I cannot point you to a specific part of the FIPS document. But in general: encrypting communication  without proper authentication of the peer means that one might actually exchange the sensitive data unknowingly with the wrong party - which would made the whole point of doing the encryption moot.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior of NOT allowing non-SunJSSE trust or key manager seems specific to Sun/Oracle JRE. Don't think it's a FIPS compliance mandate. Apparently, openSSL with FIPS enabled and libcurl doesn't have this limitation.

I am also facing issues due to this.

We have some HTTPS API calls happening in our Java application. These API calls are actually about fetching the CA certificate of remote end, displaying finger print and other details to end-user and when use accepts, persist this certificate in trust store. From then on, for subsequent HTTPS call in the workflow, will use this trust store.

So, the HTTPS call from our app to fetch the CA certificate, I have used a "trust-all" trust manager but apparently that's NOT acceptable in FIPS mode.

I agree FIPS requires tighter security and thus disabling certificate validation isn't a great idea and should NOT be done ideally. But exceptional cases like this (and probably where we wanted to perform more validations such as custom host name verification, certificate revocation status check, etc.) there should have been some provision with Sun JSSE to override this FIPS mode behavior.

Most probably, we need to implement SSLContextSpi and hook in our custom SSL context. The implementation would look very similar to SSLContextImpl below but with probably FIPS limitations relaxed. (Needless to say, this needs to be used judiciously, specially with FIPS.)

https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/raw-file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLContextImpl.java